# Python datatime object issue with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy and am having an issue wrt to an SQLite error:

```
SQLite Date type only accepts Python date objects as input. 
[SQL: 'SELECT anon_1.patient_sid AS sid FROM 
(SELECT clinical_data.patient_sid AS patient_sid FROM clinical_data 
WHERE clinical_data.event_date >= ?) AS anon_1']
```

I understand perfectly the meaning of the error, but I do not understand why it is happening in my case.

The parameter that I am passing to do the date comparison in the query above `clinical_data.event_date >= ?`, is set as:

```
valdate = datetime.strptime('1776-01-01 00:00:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
```

and, I have validated that the data type of `valdate` is `<type 'datetime.date'>`

The class used to construct the query is:

```
class ClinicalData(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'clinical_data'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    patient_id = Column(Integer)
    patient_sid  = Column(Integer)
    string_value = Column(String(255))
    double_value = Column(Float)
    data_type_id = Column(Integer)
    event_date = Column(Date)
    ontology_id = Column(Integer)
    attribute_id = Column(Integer)
    project_id = Column(Integer)
    replaced_by_id = Column(Integer)
    date_record_added = Column(DateTime)
    parent = Column(Integer)
    num_children = Column(Integer)
    lft = Column(Integer)
    rgt = Column(Integer)
```

The SQLAlchemy documentation for SQLite states (see [SQLAlchemy SQLite documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html)) that "SQLAlchemy’s own DateTime and related types provide date formatting and parsing functionality when SQlite is used..."

I am not asking how to convert my string object to a python datetime object, nor am I asking what the error means. I am not sure exactly why I keep getting this error when everything appears to be sufficiently defined.

***EDIT***

Note that when I use `DateTime` in my model on the `event_date` attribute I get the following error `SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.` For this I define `valdate = datetime.strptime('1776-01-01 00:00:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` without the `date()` method. As expected, `type(valdate)` in this case yields `<type 'datetime.datetime'>`.

I have tried every combination of creating the variable `valdate` with the `event_date` attribute of my class.

Answer (score 1):

The error says:

> SQLite Date type only accepts Python date objects as input.

But you don't have a `date` object — you have a `datetime` object!  To turn your `datetime` into a `date`, just call its [`date()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) method — though judging by the fact that your `strptime` format includes time fields (`%H:%M:%S`), you might want to change `event_date` from `Column(Date)` to `Column(DateTime)` instead.

Comment: I had tried that earlier and got the same error. Also, as noted above, I did a  'type(valdate)` and it returned `<type 'datetime.datetime'>`, which to me certainly looks and smells like a `datetime` object. I had also putzed around with the data type in my class. I tried virtually every combination under the sun.

Comment: @horcle_buzz: You seem to have missed the important part of my answer: `datetime` and `date` are two different types.  SQLAlchemy wants a `date`, but you're giving it a `datetime`.

Comment: See corrected/edited question above for further clarification.